# The saturation $J:(t_1\cdots t_m)^\infty$, where all generators of $J$ have degree one in the $t_i$'s

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, binomial-ideals

I'm currently working through [a paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0708.3431.pdf) where the authors work with lattice ideals, and one of the propositions (Proposition 6, for which only a very short proof is given) seems to rely on a seemingly simple commutative algebra claim that I haven't been able to verify (or find a counterexample to).

Here is a simplified version of it, where I've tried to clean up the notation as much as possible:

- Consider the polynomial ring $R=\mathbb{C}[\mathbf{x},\mathbf{t}]=\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n,t_1,\ldots,t_m]$.
- Let $\mathbf{a}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{a}_m\in\mathbb{N}^n$ be tuples of non-negative integers that specify monomials $\mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{a}_1},\ldots,\mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{a}_m}\in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.
- Let $J\subseteq R$ be the ideal generated by all elements of the form $t_i\mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{a}_j}-t_j\mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{a}_i}$ for $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ with $i<j$.

> **Claim:** $J:(x_1\cdots x_n\cdot t_1\cdots t_m)^\infty=J:(x_1\cdots x_n)^\infty$.

*Observation:* Since 
$$I:(x_1\cdots x_n\cdot t_1\cdots t_m)^\infty=(I:(t_1\cdots t_m)^\infty):(x_1\cdots x_n)^\infty,$$
it would suffice if we could show $J:(t_1\cdots t_m)^\infty=J$, which is what I've mostly focused on this far.

---

*Example 1:* If $m=2$, we get $J=\langle t_1\mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{a}_2}-t_2\mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{a}_1}\rangle\subseteq\mathbb{C}[\mathbf{x},t_1,t_2]$. In this case it is easy to see that $J:(t_1t_2)^\infty=J$.

A brute-force argument is this: If $f\in J:(t_1t_2)^\infty$, then there exists some $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and some $h\in\mathbb{C}[\mathbf{x},\mathbf{t}]$ such that $f\cdot (t_1 t_2)^k=h\cdot (t_1\mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{a}_2}-t_2\mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{a}_1})$. Setting $t_2=0$ gives $0=h'\cdot t_1\mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{a}_2}$, where $h'=h(\mathbf{x},t_1,0)$. Clearly we must have $h'=0$, from which it follows that $t_2$ is a factor in $h$. Similarly, one can show that $t_1$ must be a factor in $h$. Repeated use of this argument gives that $(t_1t_2)^k$ is a factor in $h$, and we conclude that $f\in J$.

---

*Example 2:* If $m=3$, we get $$J=\langle t_1\mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{a}_2}-t_2\mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{a}_1},\:\:t_1\mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{a}_3}-t_3\mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{a}_1},\:\:t_2\mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{a}_3}-t_3\mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{a}_2}\rangle\,.$$
As before, we can observe that if $f\in J:(t_1t_2t_3)^\infty$, then there exists some $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $h_{12},h_{13},h_{23}\in\mathbb{C}[\mathbf{x},\mathbf{t}]$ such that $$f\cdot (t_1t_2t_3)^k=h_{12}\cdot(t_1\mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{a}_2}-t_2\mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{a}_1})+h_{13}\cdot(t_1\mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{a}_3}-t_3\mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{a}_1})+h_{23}\cdot (t_2\mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{a}_3}-t_3\mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{a}_2})\,.$$
The desired result would follow if we could show that the $h$'s can be chosen so that they are all divisible by $t_1t_2t_3$. But is that true? Can we be sure that they don't contain any terms that aren't divisible by $t_1t_2t_3$ but then somehow cancel out? Just substituting zeros into this expression didn't turn out to be very fruitful, so I probably need a more systematic approach...

Any ideas or pushes in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: I've now added a link to the paper in question! Note, however, that the authors make no specific mention of this claim in the proof, and I'm by no means sure that this is what they are using. But if it is true, then it would explain why the ideal $T_G$ in the paper equals the lattice ideal described in the proof of Proposition 6.